# Java GroupBy multiple with Sum

Tags: java, group-by, java-stream

I'm trying to make `group by` like in mySQL, I have multiple columns (properties) and I must group by two fields (`socio` and `idSolicitudEgreso`) and sum another one (`montoPago`). I did:

```java
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mymap = santa.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Santander::getPanSocio,
                 Collectors.groupingBy(Santander::getPanIdsolicitudegreso,
                 Collectors.summingInt(Santander::getPanMontopago))));

mymap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ":" + value));
```

My class object is:

```java
public class Santander {

    private String panRutbeneficiario;
    private String panNombrebeneficiario;
    private String panEmailbeneficiario;
    private String panMetodopago;
    private String panCodigobancoabono;
    private String panTipocuentaabono;
    private String panNumcuentaabono;
    private String panFechapago;
    private String panCampobanco1;
    private String panCampobanco2;
    private int panMontopago;
    private String panTipocuentacargodet;
    private String panNumcuentacargodet;
    private String panCodigosucursal;
    private String panReferenciacliente;
    private String panRetencionfactura;
    private String panAbonovalesvistalinea;
    private String panCantidaddocumentos;
    private String panSocio;
    private String panIdsolicitudegreso;
}
```

I getting this result with this code:

**BANCO DEL ESTADO:{35113=3026882}**

As you can see I get the group very well, (`socio`, `id` and `sum` as well), but I need to get all the objects or list of object. I just get 3 of 20 fields.
What change I must do in my Java stream code to get the list of objects (grouped)? Please?

Thanks

PS: the output I expect is:

```
{  panRutbeneficiario=146174558, panNombrebeneficiario=No Definido,
   panEmailbeneficiario=, panMetodopago=CAT_CSH_TRANSFER, panCodigobancoabono=12,
   panTipocuentaabono=Ahorro, panNumcuentaabono=8275301, panFechapago=2020-07-30,
   panCampobanco1=, panCampobanco2=, panMontopago=111960,
   panTipocuentacargodet=CAT_CSH_CCTE, panNumcuentacargodet=null,
   panCodigosucursal=, panReferenciacliente=, panRetencionfactura=,
   panAbonovalesvistalinea=null, panCantidaddocumentos=null, 
   panSocio=BANCO DEL ESTADO, panIdsolicitudegreso=35113
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify list of which objects you expect? Please try to provide an expected output.

Comment: Not really clear from *"but i need to get all the object or list of object."*. If you don't perform the `summingInt` which reduces the inner values to an `Integer` sum of a single field, the inner values would be a `List<Santander>` if that's what you are looking forward to. Then you can iterate through that list and sum its `panMontopago`. for e.g. `Map<String, Map<String, List<Santander>>> mymap = santa.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Santander::getPanSocio, Collectors.groupingBy(Santander::getPanIdsolicitudegreso)));` and then perform `get` on this `Map` as desired.

Comment: {panRutbeneficiario=146174558, panNombrebeneficiario=No Definido, panEmailbeneficiario=, panMetodopago=CAT_CSH_TRANSFER, panCodigobancoabono=12, panTipocuentaabono=Ahorro, panNumcuentaabono=8275301, panFechapago=2020-07-30, panCampobanco1=, panCampobanco2=, panMontopago=111960, panTipocuentacargodet=CAT_CSH_CCTE, panNumcuentacargodet=null, panCodigosucursal=, panReferenciacliente=, panRetencionfactura=, panAbonovalesvistalinea=null, panCantidaddocumentos=null, panSocio=BANCO DEL ESTADO, panIdsolicitudegreso=35113}    That i am expecting, whete "panMontopago" is totalized

Comment: Naman, i understand you idea, but i was thinking its possible do it which stream in one sentence. Anyway i will take you idea for while. Thanks

Comment: Namman i tried you solution and i get a long list without grouping because "getPanMontopago" (money)  are diferent in every row. I would like to get just one row grouped, but for that i nedd sum "getPanMontopago".  I wont make the sum iterating the list and create my own row because i can not assume i will have only one (equal) Socio or ID  always..

Comment: @JhonMasco, why do you need `List<Santander>`?  Which values should be provided for the non-group fields then?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to prepare an object to hold the grouping result for example:

```java
public class Summary {
    private final String panSocio;
    private final String panSolicitude;
    private final int total;

    public Summary(String socio, String solicitude, int total) {
        this.panSocio = socio;
        this.panSolicitude = solicitude;
        this.total = total;
    }

    public String getPanSocio() { return this.panSocio; }
    public String getPanSolicitude() { return this.panSolicitude; }
    public int getTotal() { return this.total; }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{ socio=\"%s\", solicitude=\"%s\", total=%d}%n",
                panSocio, panSolicitude, total);
    }
}
```

Then it is possible to iterate over the entries of `mymap`, use `flatMap` to transform the entries of the inner map into `Stream<Summary>` therefore collecting into the list of `Summary` objects (sorted if necessary):

```java
List<Summary> remap = mymap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet()  // e.getKey() -> panSocio
                       .stream()               // ee.getKey() -> solicitude, ee.getValue() -> total
                       .map(ee -> new Summary(e.getKey(), ee.getKey(), ee.getValue()))
        )
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Summary::getPanSocio)
                          .thenComparing(Summary::getPanSolicitude))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Update**

Of course, it is possibe to reuse existing `Santander` class to collect the results providing that `Santander` has a constructor or builder allowing to populate at least the three relevant fields `panSocio`, `panSolicitude`, `panMontopago`:

```java
List<Santander> grouped = mymap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet()  // e.getKey() -> panSocio
                       .stream()               // ee.getKey() -> solicitude, ee.getValue() -> total
                       .map(ee -> new Santander(e.getKey(), ee.getKey(), ee.getValue())) // the rest of the fields set to some default values
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, the rest of `Santander` fields will be undefined / default upon applying `summarizingInt` collector by `Santander::getMontopago`.

Comment: where does `sorted` come into the picture from?

Comment: @Naman, Sorting is optional as I mentioned in the answner.  I made the result list sorted a) for example, b) as a minor improvement because in the test output (not given here) the order of the list was random.

Comment: Thanks Alex for you reply.